# Progress WS_FTP Professional - Issue with files having of a colon and number in front of the file name

Tags: ftp, ws

Having an issue when I drop a file from one folder to another folder in WS_FTP Professional.
We as a company have been using these to transfer some of out EDI files for several years without issues. I few weeks ago the process stopped working due to the file naming convention changed.
Now when a file is transferred it creates a file name with a : in front of the file name.
Example> :38 F478029.524.
We have another process that is expecting to find the file name (F478029.524) without the :. That process fails.
We have researched and can not find why or what the : means.
I am providing a screen shot below showing what the results look like.
Please take a look and maybe someone knows what this means. Maybe an option or setting got changed.
Thanks in in advance.

Looked and changed all types of settings and nothing changed the results.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhoDz.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).